# How to downgrade cups-filters on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, thermal-printer, printers, cups

I am facing the same problem as [the gentleman over here](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-printing@lists.debian.org/msg11253.html). That is I can't get my printer to print (but I could a few days ago).

I get the same error messages in `/var/log/cups/error_log`, the only difference being that my printer is a Brother QL-700 (monochrome label printer).

This person suggests to downgrade `cups-filters` to version 1.26.2 but I just don't know how to proceed because the only available version on the official repo is 1.28.15

```
$ apt list --all-versions cups-filters
Listing... Done
cups-filters/jammy,now 1.28.15-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]

# I should also mention that
$ apt-cache showpkg cups-filters | grep 1.26
# returns nothing
```

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.1.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or, in this case, https://askubuntu.com/ or https://superuser.com/

Comment: You are totally right, I just got so used to SO and forgot that other (more specific) platforms existed.

Comment: That said, the answer provided by Ron below really helped me. Even if the question is not on the right platform, I think future users might want to have access to this information. How should I proceed?

Comment: Your question is up for closure and will be deleted soon afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way around this is to go directly to a repo: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups-filters/

and download an older version like: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups-filters/cups-filters_1.27.4-1_amd64.deb

then install locally via:

```bash
dpkg -i cups-filters_1.27.4-1_amd64.deb
```

but you might then have to sort out any dependency issues manually.